# Laravel - route returning localhost

Tags: php, laravel-4

why is `route('charts.inline', 123123)` returning `http://localhost/charts/123123` and not my actual Domain? My ENV config/app.php url is set properly and my ENV is correct. I am running this commend through Terminal [ a 'command'].

Thoughts?

Comment: are you using xampp or wamp?

Comment: No Sir.  And nginx has the correct server name as well, so that is not the issue...

Comment: I have env(APP_URL) set to https://domainname.com and I have url set to the same domain in config.app.php as well.  route('route.name') in artisan tinker returns the proper domain.  yet when used in the applicaiton code, it returns localhost.  Any thoughts from you would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've already answered your own question:

> I am running this commend through Terminal [ a 'command']

As you're running from terminal, there's no host name to be figured out so the framework assumes `localhost` as default.

If you want to set your default domain name to properly work when running code from command line, then go to your `config/app.php` file and change the following setting from:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
 */

'url' => 'http://localhost',
```

to

```
'url' => 'http://yourdomain.com',
```

I've just tested this procedure on Laravel 5, but I hope it works for you on Laravel 4 as well.

Answer (score 2):

if you still having this issue after setting the `url` in the config, make sure that you have the protocol with your URL, i.e `https:\\example.com` instead of `example.com`, otherwise, it won't work.